# Show that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{k}{i}=2^{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

Show that $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{k}{i}=2^{k-1}$$ for every positive odd integer in the form of $k=2n+1$ ($n$ being a positive integer).

I tried the usual induction demonstration.

The case for $k=1$ is rather trivial. I'm currently stuck at the second part of the proof. I know that $\binom{k}{0}=1$ for every $k$ and $$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} = 2^n$$ but despite that I'm having trouble arriving at the desired result.

Comment: Other duplicates: (1) [Prove this using counting techniques: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{2n+1}k} = 2^{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1837106/915354); (2) [Prove the identity $\binom{2n+1}{0} + \binom{2n+1}{1} + \cdots + \binom{2n+1}{n} = 4^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1607936/915354); (3) [Find the value of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}C(2n+1,k)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2164739/915354); (4) [Proving combinatoric identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3757613/915354); (5) [Proof involving binomial sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2229581/915354).

Comment: Other duplicates (contd.): (6) [Problem proving $\sum_{r=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{r} = 2^{2n-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/941857/915354); (7) [prove $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{i}=2^{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/530676/915354); (8) [Prove identity based on binomial theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/947833/915354); (9) [Closed form of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} {2n+1 \choose k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2444518/915354); (10) [difficulties in a proof with binomial theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/997687/915354).

Comment: Other duplicates (contd.): (11) [Combinatorics Proof for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{k}=2^{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2327529/915354); (12) [Combinatorical proof $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n{{2n+1}\choose k}=2^{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/490711/915354); (13) [Proving binomial sum using mathematical induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3740022/915354).

Answer (score -1):

This follows from the symmetry in the rows of Pascal's Triangle.

Namely, the last $n+1$ numbers in row $k=2n+1$ of Pascal's Triangle are just the first $n+1$ numbers in reverse order, and so the sum of the first $n+1$ numbers ($\binom{k}{0}$ to $\binom{k}{n}$) is half of the sum of all the numbers in row $k$, which is equal to $\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2^k=2^{k-1}$.